# I want to disable html tags when I update my html to database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I create a php application. In which I store html pages in mysql and retrieve from db. I design it for delete or add data in the pages, so I create database, so now problem is when I want to edit the data which are placed in textarea it save and update but in textarea it show all the text with html codes etc which is painful to extract and modify text in whole page.

Is there any method that will not display html tags and which tags I want to show or hide.

Is any solution in mysql side or php side.

Comment: Consider using [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax).

Comment: use editor - Ex: tinymce

Answer (score 0):

You can use [php strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) method.

```
<?php
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text);
echo "\n";

// Allow <p> and <a>
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');
?>
```

Comment: it will remove all the HTML tags

Comment: If you read carefully, you can see that you can exclude tags (see the second argument of the method)

Comment: second parameter is about the allowable_tags. we can't write all the html tags if we just need to remove only one specific tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to keep the HTML formatting so that when it is displayed on the page it has HTML markup around it (which sounds like the original plan) then you could use a WYSIWIG editor. Here's a couple:

- http://www.tinymce.com/
- http://ckeditor.com/

They can both be configured to allow whatever HTML elements you want.
Remember to validate and verify when processed by PHP though.
I've recently started using HTML Purifier for checking the HTML.

- http://htmlpurifier.org/

If you're not interested in keeping HTML formatting then just use `strip_tags()`.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Answer (score 0):

Your problem refers to the client-side and WYSIWYG JS-libraries, which will make editing of texts more comfortable.

Take a look at these solutions:

- [WYMeditor](http://www.wymeditor.org)
- [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com)
- [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the HTML DOM, which will allow you to add,delete,edit any element. I will recommend you to use [simple_html_dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) [php native DOM](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

Here is Example to remove specific html tag using simple html dom

```
<?php

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load('<html><body><span>removeme</span></body></html>');
$html->set_callback('remove_tag');

function remove_tag($element)
{
 if($element->tag == 'span'){ $element->outertext = ""; 
}
```

?>

You can also use a regular expression to remove specific tag

```
<?php

$html = preg_replace("/<span[^>]+\>/i", "", $html);

?>
```